# terminate execution by parent method

Tags: php, inheritance, terminate

I have the following code:

```
class A
{
   function example($bool)
   {
      echo "Bob";
      if($bool === true)
      {
         //how to terminate?
      }
   }
}

class B extends A
{
   function example($bool)
   {
      echo "Alice";
      parent::example($bool);
      echo "Charlie";
   }
}
```

if i call

```
$x = new B;
$x->example(false);
```

i´ll get "AliceBobCharlie" as expected

and what i want is that if i pass true only "AliceBob" will appear. say: i want to terminate the execution of $x->example in the parent-method

i hope you got me. how to do this?

thanks for your help

Comment: afaik there is no native multithreading in PHP, so you can't kill the proccess from outside, because you don't have an outside thread to do it

Comment: @0xDEADBEEF: you cannot do that, apart calling exit or die and kill the whole script ... love your nickname by the way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well...either you return a boolean from `A::example()` and check it in `B::example()` to decide if you should continue.

If you really want to have an interrupt, you can throw an exception. Using exceptions to handle control-flow is bad design however.